# How can I remove a link from top.links in Magento Header?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

I am currently using Magento 2.2 and have a marketplace module installed that added a "sell" link into a header dropdown. This header dropdown calls 'top.links' as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-toplinks">
                    <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="pe-7s-user"></i></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('top.links') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In my default.xml file, the links included are:

```
<referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
```

I can not find the top.links file, it does not seem to exist. Is there any way to remove just the singular "sell" link? (The other links that exist are My Account, Sign in, My Wishlist).

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `default.xml` file,

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: How to rearrange the links in the dropdown of top links?